# Como Insertar una fila desde php a google spreadsheet

Tags: php, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el cual quiero automatizar una serie de cosas, lo que necesito es saber como desde php puedo insertar una fila o filas en google spreadsheet.

He leído que se puede desarrollar a través de la librería `google_spreasheet` y de `zend gdata`, pero no me quiero arriesgar a instalar librerías en el servidor, ya que tengo muchas cosas y no quiero que afecte a nada, pero si se ha de hacer así lo haré, me gustaría que me ayudaran a realizar el codigo en php, y si he de instalar una librería en el server que me digan como.

Comment: Te dejo el enlace a la documentación [PHP Quickstart | Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/php) que te podría ser de utilidad para empezar.

Comment: Gracias por la documentación ya me la revise, esto ya lo hice, el problema que tengo es el tema de insertar una fila en el sheet con las variables del formulario, he visto que hay muchas librerias pero las he de instalar en el servidor de mi hosting compartido, no se si esto puede afectar a todo el php de mi web y demas? es por ello que estoy pidiendo ayudar ya que no consigo avanzar en este tema.

Comment: Ya lo pude resolver, gracias a composer y la instalación de unas librerias puedo insertar en google sheet los paraemtros introducidos en el formulario de mi Landin page,